# NgMessage not working in Angular Directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, ng-messages

HTML that worked because placing in directive

```
<div class="col-md-12" style="margin-top: 5px;">
    <div class="form-group-sm" ng-class="{'has-error': (orderDetailsForm.CustomerNameKey.$invalid && orderDetailsForm.CustomerNameKey.$touched) || (orderDetailsForm.CustomerNameKey.$invalid && vmRequest.submittingRequest)}">
        <label class="col-md-2 control-label text-nowrap">Customer Name Key:</label>

        <div class="col-md-3" ng-class="{'has-error': (orderDetailsForm.CustomerNameKey.$invalid && orderDetailsForm.CustomerNameKey.$touched) || (orderDetailsForm.CustomerNameKey.$invalid && vmRequest.submittingRequest)}">
            <input replace="[^a-zA-Z]" with="" maxlength="4" type="text" id="CustomerNameKey" name="CustomerNameKey" class="form-control" ng-model="detail.customerNameKey" placeholder="Customer Name Key" required />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So above worked. However, I have to make a web api call and get a check back to see whether to even display this or not

Thus I have a directive that calls a service and then based on that, use ng-include to the correct html template.

My call to the directive

```
 <div ng-if="detail.program.ldcCode.length > 0">
     <lcd-code lcdcode="{{ detail.program.ldcCode }}"></lcd-code>
</div>
```

**Directive**

```
(function () {

    var lcdCode = function (customerService) {
        return {
            replace: true,
            restrict: "E",
            scope: {
                lcdcode: '@'
            },
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                var promise = customerService.getKey(attrs.lcdcode)
                    .then(function (result) {

                        scope.url = "";

                        scope.getContentUrl = function () {
                            if (result === 1) {
                                scope.url = '/app/request/templates/keyRequired.html?v=1';
                            } else {
                                scope.url = '/app/request/templates/empty.html?v=1';
                            }
                            return scope.url;
                        }

                    })
                    .catch(function () {
                        console.log('problem');
                    });

            },
            template: '<div ng-include="getContentUrl()"></div>'

        };
    };

    angular.module('app').directive('lcdCode', lcdCode)

}());
```

Something I read and was trying was to pass the form

So I tried in HTML to pass the form in

```
<lcd-code orderDetailsForm="orderDetailsForm" lcdcode="{{ detail.program.ldcCode }}"></lcd-code>
```

Next in the Directive pass in the form

```
orderDetailsForm: '=',
```

I used that name `orderDetailsForm`  since the `keyRequired.html` template already has values like that

```
ng-messages="orderDetailsForm.CustomerNameKey.$error"
```

So I read and tried passing in form,  looked into link and compiler stuff  - I'm not sure what problem is

Comment: Can you create plnkr or fidde file ?

Comment: Just use async validation as it designed - whats the point of inventing something here